# CFSPREADSHEET read in Excel file to query can't access columns in result

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

I'm trying to automate processing of spreadsheets using ColdFusion 10 and CFSpreadSheet.  So far I can read the file in and dump the query object without any issue.

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#theFile#" query="qData" headerrow="1" columns="1,8,9,11,33"/>
<cfdump var="#qData#"/>
```

[image: cfdumpoutput]

The issue comes when I try to work with the data.  If I do something like:

```
<cfoutput query="qData" maxrows="#qData.RecordCount#">
    #qData.GROUP#<br />
    #qData.DOB#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

I immediately get an error: "Element GROUP is undefined in QDATA."

If I dump the qData.ColumnList I get a column list:

```
BTBN(002),DOB ,GROUP ,MEMBER/DEPENDENT NAME ,REL
```

Is it the spaces and ( )s messing it up?  If so, how can I get rid of those and update the column names either when reading in the file or immediately thereafter?

Answer (score 3):

I initially thought it may be due to "group" being a reserved SQL keyword.  (Don't try using that columnname in a query-of-queries.)

Instead of sanitizing the first row values for known values and resaving the file, you should loop through and use isValid("variablename", ColumnName) to determine if the column name is valid and then use the RenameColumn UDF to rename it.  We prefer this method as it's critical that we don't modify the client's original Excel file (especially since Adobe ColdFusion has some bugs when writing files and will likely mess up other worksheets and/or formatting within the file.)

An easy way to remove illegal characters is to use rereplace:

```
ReReplace(NewColumnName, "[^a-zA-Z0-9!]", "", "ALL")
```

But you'll also need to ensure that the new column name isn't empty, starts with a letter and isn't already used for another column.  If you are expecting the columns to be in a certain order, you could simply safely rename them "col_1" (or use numbering as a default fallback for any non-unique and/or illegal column names.)

Here's the RenameColumn UDF taken from this 2011 blog post:

http://www.neiland.net/blog/article/using-java-to-rename-columns-in-a-coldfusion-query-object/

```
<cffunction name="renameColumn" access="public" output="false" returntype="query" hint="Uses java to rename a given query object column">
  <cfargument name="queryObj" required="true" type="query">
  <cfargument name="oldColName" required="true" type="string">
  <cfargument name="newColName" required="true" type="string">

  <!--- Get an array of the current column names --->
  <cfset var colNameArray = queryObj.getColumnNames()>
  <cfset var i = 0>

  <!--- Loop through the name array and try match the current column name with the target col name--->
  <cfif arrayLen(colNameArray)>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(colNameArray)#" index="i">
              <!--- If we find the target col name change to the new name --->
              <cfif compareNoCase(colNameArray[i],arguments.oldColName) EQ 0>
                    <cfset colNameArray[i] = arguments.newColName>
              </cfif>
        </cfloop>
  </cfif>

  <!--- Update the column names with the updated name array --->
  <cfset queryObj.setColumnNames(colNameArray)>

  <cfreturn queryObj />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: One note: ColdFusion's `isValid("variableName")` has a known bug/feature and trims the string before evaluating it, so you'll need to also manually check for leading/trailing spaces in the column name.

Answer (score 1):

(In case folks do not read the comments ...)

The parenthesis and slashes will be problematic as they do not conform to the [standard variable name rules](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd3.html). The simplest option is to use the ["columnNames" attribute](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfspreadsheet.html) to specify valid column names instead. (Also, nothing to do with your question, but if you want to exclude the header row, use `excludeHeaderRow="true"`)

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="c:\path\file.xlsx" 
     query="qData" 
     columnNames="BTBN_002,DOB,GROUP_NAME,MEMBER_DEPEND_NAME,REL"
     excludeHeaderRow="true"
     headerrow="1" 
     ... />
```

In most cases, you can also access invalid column names using associative array notation. However, using the "columnNames" attribute is simpler/cleaner IMO.

```
<cfoutput query="qData" maxrows="#qData.RecordCount#">
    #qData["BTBN(002)"][currentRow]#<br />
    ....
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION - there were multiple spaces in the column names and ColdFusion does not tolerate that.  This could probably be done better with a regex, and I'll work on that next but here's the quick and dirty solution.

```
<cfset colNameArray = qData.getColumnNames() />

<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(colNameArray)#" index="i">
  <cfset colNameArray[i] = colNameArray[i].replace(' ','') />
  <cfset colNameArray[i] = colNameArray[i].replace('(','') />
  <cfset colNameArray[i] = colNameArray[i].replace(')','') />
  <cfset colNameArray[i] = colNameArray[i].replace('/','') />
</cfloop>      

<cfset qData.setColumnNames(colNameArray) />
```

Comment: Just use the "columnNames" attribute to assign whatever column names you want :) You could also use array notation to access the invalid column names ie `#query["BTBN(002)"][currentRow]#` but "columnNames" is simpler/cleaner IMO.

Comment: I highly recommend clients use "ASAP Utilities" for Excel to trim all values prior to upload.  It also has a function to quickly convert formulas to values so that ColdFusion doesn't throw an error attempting to determine the value. http://www.asap-utilities.com/  (It also strips the invisible non-breaking space that plagues many Excel files that doesn't get removed with trim() and is imported into SQL.)